# Public Header Path, Installation Directory, Search Header Path and other nightmares

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a project composed of 2 libraries (libraryA and libraryB) and a bundle. Each one of these were created like a project and imported on the main project by dragging them.

Just dragging them were not enough for Xcode to find all headers to compile the whole project, so I had to hack the paths using hard ones but this is bad because paths can change and I will not be able to compile this project again. I want to use macros like [these ones](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html) to access the files, but after testing almost all of them, I was not able to make it work.

The solution I have to make the compilation work is the following.

I have adjusted each library in a way that their public headers are saved inside

```
/Users/rubberduck/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-dnaimaovsccuvieahmvgttwjnabc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/
```

using target names, so after they compile they will put their public headers on

```
/Users/rubberduck/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-dnaimaovsccuvieahmvgttwjnabc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libraryA
```

and

```
/Users/rubberduck/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-dnaimaovsccuvieahmvgttwjnabc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libraryB
```

The problem now is that libraryB needs libraryA's headers to compile. If these are siblings directories what should I put on libraryB's headers search path to point to libraryA's.

NOTE: I need a path that is not hardcoded but rather using one of those macros I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly a Xcode bug or limitation.

The only solution I had for this was to import the subproject used by a project several times in the same workspace.

For example: suppose I had a libraryA used by the main project and also by libraryB. All I did to make Xcode compile was to import libraryA two times on the same workspace, one for libraryB and one for the main project and everything compiled fine.

Xcode 4 is poorly designed by Apple, from the interface to the engine and now I understand why so many people hate it (62% in a website poll).

Answer (score 1):

Apple seems to have departed from the public header path as the preferred mechanism for static library includes, probably due to these types of complexities.  If you create a new static library project, it will instead have a "Copy Files" build phase where header files are copied into `"Products Directory"` with the subpath `"include/${PRODUCT_NAME}"`.

When you import headers, instead of using `#import "header1.h"` you will use `#import <MyProduct/header1.h>`.  I believe the libraries need to be build before it can compile, but this shouldn't be an issue if they are included in your "Link Binary With Libraries" phase.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with,

Add a “Source Tree” variable that Xcode can use to dynamically find Lib.
**In Xcode preferences > “Locations” button > “Source Trees” tab > create a new Source Tree variable.**
For Lib, create **LIB_SRC** and let it point to **/path_to_lib/lib/src/**
Be careful: Xcode does not allow the path to contain any spaces!

Comment: after creating this source tree variable what do I do with it? where do I use it?

Comment: use this variable at search path

Comment: ok, this is what I did: I added this variable and changed all PUBLIC HEADER fields of all labs to point to this. Then changed all HEADER SEARCH PATHS and all LIBRARY SEARCH PATHS to point to this. Final results: now I have not 7 compiler errors, but 50. If this is not how this should be used, please elaborate more your answer. Sorry but you are very telegraphic here.

Comment: Sorry for that, You need to use that variable at Library search path so Xcode will find that path using that variable and you need to add set Other linker Flag -ObjC, -all_load. May be it helps you?

Comment: Be careful: Xcode does not allow the path to contain any spaces!